# Using Jquery to adjust text size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to let the user select what font size they would like, and it increases the font size of only #text. Now I tried a few different things but nothing seemed to work. I just want it so the can click up or down arrow and it makes it larger by 1px each time they click. However only a range from 10-80 otherwise it will give an error.

I will post the code below for the html and js. Gonna keep working on it since I got the colors, font family, and bold/italic buttons to work already.

Thank you

HTML/JS

```
**<select id="font">
    <h2>Font Size</h2>
    <input type="text" name="font" value="15" id="font" /> px
    <br /><span id="sizeWarning"></span>
</select>**



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buttonup').click(function(){   
        curSize= parseInt($('#text').css('font-size')) + 2;  if(curSize<=20)
        $('#text').css('font-size', curSize);
        }); 
  $('#buttondown').click(function(){   
        curSize= parseInt($('#text').css('font-size')) - 2;
  if(curSize>=12)
        $('#text').css('font-size', curSize);
        });
 });
```

Comment: One question at a time, please. Off topic: Only one instance of document.ready is necessary. All functions go inside.

Comment: sorry about that. and yes i knew that, just usually clean up the code after i am all set.

Comment: That doesn't show much regard for the volunteers who are willing to help.

Comment: Ah true, sorry I will clean it up. Sorry about that

Comment: How about ripping out all the code that's not relevant to this specific question. I don't see where you're trying to change font size.

Comment: done, just trying to make it, so that selector button can increase the font if clicked up, or decrease it if the down button is clicked. Or the user could enter the font size in the input box

Comment: tbh if i can only get what the user inputs in the text box to change the size , that would be fine. just not let him/her enter below 10 or above 80

Comment: Hi! Could you post your Javascript / jQuery code?

Comment: sure, see i only know how to do it if there is 2 buttons, one to decrease and one to increase. Not sure how to take the number they enter and do it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made a simple example (updated, added some checking that font-size only 10-80):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XfHR7/2/

JS:

```
$("#up").click(function () {
    var currentSize = $("#text").css("font-size");
    currentSize = currentSize.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    currentSize++;
    if(currentSize < 10 || currentSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + currentSize + "px");
    }
});

$("#down").click(function () {
    var currentSize = $("#text").css("font-size");
    currentSize = currentSize.replace(/[^\d.]/g, "");
    currentSize--;
    if(currentSize < 10 || currentSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + currentSize + "px");
    }

});

$("input#inputSize").on("keyup change", function () {
    var newSize = $(this).val();
    if(newSize < 10 || newSize > 80){
        alert("Font-size between 10 and 80 only!");
    }
    else {
        $("#text").css("font-size", "" + newSize + "px");
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<p id="text">Text, yay!</p>
<span id="up">Up</span><br />
<span id="down">Down</span><br />
change size via input: <input id="inputSize" type="number" step="1" value="20" max="80" min="10" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much, really helped. For some reason it is not working tho, gonna keep looking, it works awesome in jfiddle, and since the text I am trying to change is #text, I left that. I think its because my input thing is surrounded by a <selector> tab. Can i mod the jquery to incorporate that somehow, as I am not supposed to remove the selector tag. If you check out my OP at the top of the code its there. Ill keep messing around

Comment: @user3321452 Hmm, your HTML code which you provided seems to be pretty messed up. You can only have `<option>` tags inside `<select>` tag. Your code is not valid HTML. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/XfHR7/4/ I fixed your HTML and created JavaScript which generates `<select>` tags between 10 and 80. I also updated that jQuery code to listen also that `#font` element.

Comment: Thank you very much, got it working now with valid code!